# Cannot authorize to Exchange Server with daemon app - Get 403: The token contains not enough scope to make this call

Tags: php, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I try to connect to a on premise Exchange 2013-Server via EWS with a daemon php-app to fetch calendar items from different users/ressources. The App is registered in Azure AD and got the the application permission "full_access_as_app" and "Calendars.ReadWrite.All"  I am able retrieve a token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID/oauth2/v2.0/token which includes the following roles:

```
"aud": "https://mail.TENANT.URL",
...
"roles": [
    "full_access_as_app",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
```

With this token a make following soap call:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/>
        <ns1:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <ns1:ConnectingSID>
                <ns1:PrimarySmtpAddress>resource@tenant.url</ns1:PrimarySmtpAddress>
            </ns1:ConnectingSID>
        </ns1:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
            <ns2:ItemShape>
                <ns1:BaseShape>AllProperties</ns1:BaseShape>
            </ns2:ItemShape>
            <ns2:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="100" StartDate="2021-05-01T00:00:00+02:00"
                              EndDate="2021-12-31T00:00:00+01:00"/>
            <ns2:ParentFolderIds>
                <ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
            </ns2:ParentFolderIds>
        </ns2:FindItem>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I get 403 response from the server:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response
  -reasonPhrase: "Forbidden"
  -statusCode: 403
  -headers: array:17 [
    "Date" => array:1 [
      0 => "Fri, 24 Sep 2021 07:51:14 GMT"
    ]
    "Server" => array:1 [
      0 => "Apache"
    ]
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [
      0 => "private"
    ]
        ...
    "x-ms-diagnostics" => array:1 [
      0 => "2000008;reason="The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant""
    ]
```

I tried to hard code a `X-AnchorMailbox` header, as suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webdav_101/best-practices-ews-authentication-and-access-issues, Always set X-AnchorMailbox when using EWS Impersonation:

```
$postOptions = array(
            'body' => $request,
            'headers' => array(
                'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive',
                'User-Agent' => 'PHP-SOAP-CURL',
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                'SOAPAction' => $action,
                'X-AnchorMailbox' => 'resource@tenant.url'
            ),
            'verify' => $this->validate,
            'http_errors' => false
        );
```

But this changes nothing ..

What am I missing? With "full_access_as_app", and  "Calendars.ReadWrite.All" a should have the permission to the calendar items. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't need Calendar.ReadWrite.All eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/connect-exchange-server-onprem-hma, is Hybrid Modern Authentication configured and working otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Glen! It was indeed a configuration missing on server side! It is now working!

Comment: @janh-kramer could you please share what exactly you did? What "configuration"?